# Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 1, whereas the Loader expects 4 in ... on line 0

Tags: php, zend-optimizer

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 and for some time I had to keep a downgraded PHP 5.2 package because I need to run Zend encrypted scripts. Recently I noticed that Zend released beta version of their loader (http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=1365&start=80#p22073) so I updated to the native PHP 5.3 package, downloaded the .so file, added this to php.ini

```
;zend_extension=/etc/php5/ZendOptimizer.so
zend_extension=/etc/php5/ZendGuardLoader.so
zend_loader.enable=1
zend_loader.disable_licensing=0
zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support=3
```

and restarted the server. Now I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Incompatible file format: The encoded file has format major ID 1, whereas the Loader expects 4 in ...  on line 0

Do you by chance know an easy fix for this? Or should I downgrade back and wait till when they release something more stable?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to re-encode your scripts with the newer version of Gaurd.

From: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=6595

> Please note this Loader will not load PHP 5.2 code encoded with previous version of Guard. All PHP files must be re-encoded to run in PHP 5.3.